# pyglet errors for python3

Tags: python, download, pyglet

The pyglet module on my computer isn't working. I've tried a lot of suggestions from others and none of them have worked.

First I tried pip3 install pyglet. But when I tried to run code I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chervjay/Downloads/gameloop.py", line 5, in <module>
from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 236, in <module>
import pyglet.window
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1816, in <module>
gl._create_shadow_window()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 205, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 493, in __init__
display = get_platform().get_default_display()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1765, in get_default_display
return pyglet.canvas.get_display()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/__init__.py", line 82, in get_display
return Display()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/carbon.py", line 22, in __init__
import MacOS
ImportError: No module named 'MacOS'
```

Then I commented out the lines that use MacOS in carbon.py, which are only 2, and ran it again, and this time it said

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chervjay/Downloads/gameloop.py", line 132, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "/Users/chervjay/Downloads/gameloop.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.hud = Hud(self.win)
  File "/Users/chervjay/Downloads/gameloop.py", line 97, in __init__
    color=(1, 1, 1, 0.5),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/font/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    group=self._group)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 791, in __init__
    self.document = document
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 874, in _set_document
    self._init_document()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 977, in _init_document
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 911, in _update
    lines = self._get_lines()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 887, in _get_lines
    glyphs = self._get_glyphs()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 1016, in _get_glyphs
    glyphs.extend(font.get_glyphs(text[start:end]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/font/base.py", line 378, in get_glyphs
    self.glyphs[c] = glyph_renderer.render(c)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/font/carbon.py", line 240, in render
    text_ucs2 = str_ucs2(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/font/carbon.py", line 194, in str_ucs2
    return create_string_buffer(text + '\0')
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

I have tried 
`pip3.5 install --upgrade http://pyglet.googlecode.com/archive/tip.zip` and got the same errors. I cannot find any other answers.

Please help if you know how to. Thank you.

I got the code I'm trying to run from http://tartley.com/?p=250.

Comment: Mind telling us what OSX version you're running?

Comment: OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.6